# Build npm dependency's sources with Brunch

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, babeljs, brunch

I've been trying to build my web application with Brunch. It depends on a certain npm package ([animated-vue](https://npmjs.com/package/animated-vue)), which only contains sources and has been programming using ES2016.

Every time I try to build my project, after adding said package as a dependency, I get the following error:

```
Processing of node_modules/animated-vue/src/index.js failed. SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (5:4)
```

That usually means the module is not being transpiled by babel, which is one of my devDependencies too.

I wonder if someone could lend me a hand on how to fix this?

Here is my **brunch-config.js** file:

```
module.exports = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        'vendor.js': /^(?!app)/, // Files that are not in `app` dir.
        'app.js': /^app/
      }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: 'app.css'/*{
        'vendor.css': /^(?!app)/,
        'app.js': /^app/
      }*/
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: 'app.js'
    }
  },
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      presets: ['latest', 'stage-3']
    },
    vue: {
      extractCSS: false
    },
    sass: {
      mode: "native",
      precision: 8,
      options: {
        includePaths: [
          'node_modules/bulma'
        ]
      }
    },
    copycat: {
      'fonts': ['node_modules/font-awesome/fonts']
    }
  },
  npm: {
    styles: {
      'izitoast': ['dist/css/iziToast.css'],
      'font-awesome': ['css/font-awesome.css'],
      'animate.css': ['animate.css']
    }
  }
}
```

And here my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "wannaworkthere",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "UI for the wannaworkthere package",
  "main": "public/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "brunch w --server",
    "build:local": "brunch b",
    "build:production": "PRODUCTION=true brunch b --production"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gitlab.com/srodriki/wannaworkthere.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "vue",
    "brunch",
    "vuex",
    "vue-router"
  ],
  "author": "Rodrigo Juliani <srodriki@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/srodriki/wannaworkthere/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/srodriki/wannaworkthere#README",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.22.0",
    "brunch": "^2.10.6",
    "copycat-brunch": "^1.1.0",
    "process-env-brunch": "^1.4.5",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.10.4",
    "vue-brunch": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^3.5.2",
    "animated-vue": "^0.1.5",
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "bulma": "^0.3.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "izitoast": "^1.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "store": "^1.3.20",
    "vee-validate": "^2.0.0-beta.25",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-router": "^2.2.0",
    "vuex": "^2.1.2"
  }
}
```

Anyone able to help me sort this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the key to this problem is setting `npm.compilers` to `['babel-brunch']` and taking care that the files aren't ignored by `babel_brunch`.

See [this issue](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1582) for a detailed discussion and [this repository](https://github.com/afrz/brunch-issue-1582) for a full working example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fox32 for the info! It indeed seems weird that a special config is needed for babel-brunch since brunch's premise is to work with non-transpiled npm dependencies and doesn't make much sense to me but it indeed works the way you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the order of the execution of the Brunch packages.  Even though it's not good practice, can you try to put the babel plugins directly before your troubled plugin?

> It’s worth noting that plugin order matters (as in, the order in which
>   they’re listed in package.json)

As it is written in [the Brunch guide](https://github.com/brunch/brunch-guide/blob/master/content/en/chapter11-plugins.md#enabling-a-plugin). Also, take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/1377).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I believe you're right about the plugin order. I shall test a few changes in ordering and see what happens.